# Displaying null value when attempting to display value retrieved from Server object

Tags: java, swing

To update the question, I've attached the Product and Customer classes they are below the Server and Client classes

I'll apologize in advance here if I'm unclear.  I'm trying to display a `String` value contained in an `ArrayList` in a `JTextField`. The `String` value does display but the `null` value does also and I would like to display the `String` value.  This is the example `String` value being displayed in the `JTextField`

```
[nullDamonTholsonnull0, nullSylvesterStallonenull0, nullMisterTnull0]
[nullDamonTholsonnull0, nullSylvesterStallonenull0, nullMisterTnull0]
[nullDamonTholsonnull0, nullSylvesterStallonenull0, nullMisterTnull0]
```

In my program I have Client user interface requesting the `String` values from a `Server` `Object` and then Displaying them in a `JTextField`. Here is the Client interface code:

```
private void jButtonDisplaycNamesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 67);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataRequest request = new DataRequest(DataRequest.NAME);
            out.writeObject(request);
            out.flush();

            List<Customer> customerNames = (List<Customer>) in.readObject();
            jTextAreaOutput.setText("");

            for (Customer customerName : customerNames) {
                jTextAreaOutput.append(customerNames.toString());
                jTextAreaOutput.append("\n");
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "unable to contact Server");
            Logger.getLogger(ClientGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void jButtonDisplaycIDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 67);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataRequest request = new DataRequest(DataRequest.ID);
        out.writeObject(request);
        out.flush();
        List<Customer> customerIDs = (List<Customer>) in.readObject();
        jTextAreaOutput.setText("");
        for (Customer customerID : customerIDs) {
            jTextAreaOutput.append(customerIDs.toString());
            jTextAreaOutput.append("\n");
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "unable to contact Server");
        Logger.getLogger(ClientGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void jButtonDisplaypIDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    {
        try {

            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 67);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataRequest request = new DataRequest(DataRequest.PRODUCTID);
            out.writeObject(request);
            out.flush();

            List<Product> productIDs = (List<Product>) in.readObject();
            jTextAreaOutput.setText("");

            for (Product procuctID : productIDs) {
                jTextAreaOutput.append(productIDs.toString());
                jTextAreaOutput.append("\n");
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "unable to contact Server");
            Logger.getLogger(ClientGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
}
```

And here is the Server Object code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(67);
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        DataRequest request = (DataRequest) in.readObject();

        switch (request.getDataType()) {
            case DataRequest.NAME:
                out.writeObject(getCustomerName());
                out.flush();
                break;

            case DataRequest.ID:
                out.writeObject(getCustomerID());
                out.flush();
                break;

            case DataRequest.PASSWORD:
                out.writeObject(getCustomerPassword());
                out.flush();
                break;

            case DataRequest.DESCRIPTION:
                out.writeObject(getProductDescription());
                out.flush();
                break;
            case DataRequest.PRODUCTID:
                out.writeObject(getProductDescription());
                out.flush();
                break;

            case DataRequest.PRICE:
                out.writeObject(getProductDescription());
                out.flush();
                break;

        }
    }
}

private static List<Customer> getCustomerName() {
    List<Customer> names = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    in.readObject;
    Customer name = new Customer();
    name.setcFirstName("Damon");

    name.setcLastName("Tholson");

    names.add(name);

    name = new Customer();

    name.setcFirstName("Sylvester");
    name.setcLastName("Stallone");
    names.add(name);

    name = new Customer();

    name.setcFirstName("Mister");
    name.setcLastName("T");
    names.add(name);

    return names;
}
```

public class Customer implements Serializable{

```
private String cID;
private String cFirstName;
private String cLastName;
private String cPassword;
private int dataType;




/**
 * @return the cID
 */
public String getcID() {
    return cID;
}

/**
 * @param cID the cID to set
 */
public void setcID(String cID) {
    this.cID = cID;
}

/**
 * @return the cFirstName
 */
public String getcFirstName() {
    return cFirstName;
}

/**
 * @param cFirstName the cFirstName to set
 */
public void setcFirstName(String cFirstName) {
    this.cFirstName = cFirstName;
}

/**
 * @return the cLastName
 */
public String getcLastName() {
    return cLastName;
}

/**
 * @param cLastName the cLastName to set
 */
public void setcLastName(String cLastName) {
    this.cLastName = cLastName;
}

/**
 * @return the cPassword
 */
public String getcPassword() {
    return cPassword;
}

/**
 * @param cPassword the cPassword to set
 */
public void setcPassword(String cPassword) {
    this.cPassword = cPassword;
}

/**
 * @return the dataType
 */
public int getDataType() {
    return dataType;
}

/**
 * @param dataType the dataType to set
 */
public void setDataType(int dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  cID + cFirstName + cLastName +  cPassword +  dataType ;
}
```

public class Product implements Serializable {

```
private String pID;

private String pDescription;
private String pPrice;
private int dataType;



/**
 * @return the pID
 */
public String getpID() {
    return pID;
}

/**
 * @param pID the pID to set
 */
public void setpID(String pID) {
    this.pID = pID;
}

/**
 * @return the pName
 */
/**
 * @return the pDescription
 */
public String getpDescription() {
    return pDescription;
}

/**
 * @param pDescription the pDescription to set
 */
public void setpDescription(String pDescription) {
    this.pDescription = pDescription;
}

/**
 * @return the pPrice
 */
public String getpPrice() {
    return pPrice;
}

/**
 * @param pPrice the pPrice to set
 */
public void setpPrice(String pPrice) {
    this.pPrice = pPrice;
}

public int getDataType() {
    return dataType;
}

/**
 * @param dataType the dataType to set
 */
public void setDataType(int dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return pID + pDescription + pPrice;
}

/**
 * @return the dataType
 */
```

}

Comment: You will, very quickly, want to have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: What does the `Customer` class look like? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Can you post the Customer and Product class code? Or at least, the toString methods of that classes. Maybe the problem can be solved modifying that methods.

Comment: You're never closing the accepted socket.

Comment: I thought I closed it at the end of the switch statement in the Server class with the command socket.close();

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why I would I would close it.  I thought I wanted the server socket open all the time to accept requests from the Client.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Client class which was calling the output of the toString method in the Customer class.  I had multiple returns in the toString method but I was only calling for one return so I was recieving the variable I called for and null values for the variables which I didn't call for. so my toString method was returning the following:

@Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return   cFirstName + cID + cLastName +cPassword;
    }

However my Client class was only calling for one variable out of that method

for (Customer customerName : customerNames) 
                {
                    jTextAreaOutput.append(customerName.toString());

```
            }
```

So I changed to call for a specific variable

for (Customer customerName : customerNames) 
                {
                    jTextAreaOutput.append(customerName.getcFirstName());

```
            }
```